# Java - How does an xml document loads a DTD using XML Catalogs?

Tags: java, xml, xslt, saxon, dtd

I want to know this so I can apply xsl transformations to the xml document without losing some entities like `&ndash;`

How do I tell the parser (any parser I dont care) which catalog to use and then execute the xsl transformations?, How do I connect the new configured parser to the transformation factory.

The code below represents the transformations I want to execute on the xml file (it works fine). I just want to know how can I add the XML Catalog approach so the xml-document loads correctly its DTD and continue with the xsl transformations steps.

```
        try {
        SAXTransformerFactory stf = (SAXTransformerFactory) TransformerFactory.newInstance();


        Templates step1Template = stf.newTemplates(new StreamSource(
                this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("xsltransformation_step1.xsl")
        ));

        Templates step2Template = stf.newTemplates(new StreamSource(
                this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("xsltransformation_step2.xsl")
        ));

       Templates step3Template = stf.newTemplates(new StreamSource(
               this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("xsltransformation_step3.xsl")
        ));

        TransformerHandler th1 = stf.newTransformerHandler(step1Template);
        TransformerHandler th2 = stf.newTransformerHandler(step2Template);
        TransformerHandler th3 = stf.newTransformerHandler(step3Template);

        StreamSource xmlStreamSource = new StreamSource(new File(xmlInputFile));

        StreamResult outputStreamSource1 = new StreamResult(new File (outputNewFile1));
        StreamResult outputStreamSource2 = new StreamResult(new File (outputNewFile2));

        th1.setResult(new SAXResult(th2));
        th2.setResult(new SAXResult(th3));
        th3.setResult(outputStreamSource1);

        Transformer t = stf.newTransformer();
        t.transform(xmlStreamSource, new SAXResult(th1));


    }catch (TransformerException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
```

This is an example of the xmlInputFile containing entities

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE manual PUBLIC '-//docufy//Docufy Standard DTD 20080125//EN' '/system/cosimago/dtd/manual.dtd'>
<chapter>
  <title>LEDs &#8222;5 &ndash; 8&#8220; am CPU-Board pr&#252;fen</title>
  <body>
   <!-- just content -->
  </body>
</chapter>
```

Please I would be really thankful if some good soul help me out with this.

Thank you in advance.

Andres

Comment: So where do you have entity references like `&ndash;`? In the original XML input `xmlInputFile`? It would help if you show exactly which input you have and which result you get as well as the one you expect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21006120/replace-text-in-xml-before-xslt/21008413#21008413

Comment: @MartinHonnen Hi Martin, yes entity references are in the XmlInputFile. I added an example of the input I have. I dont get any result yet because the xml document does not load its DTD. The result I want is that it loads the DTD, resolve the entities and finally allows the xsl transformations to execute on it

Comment: XML catalogs are a way to _not_ load the DTDs over the net, immensely speeding up in the case of those HMTL entities. It is so crucial, you better research on it, instead of picking a "working" answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's simplest to create your own XML parser (`XMLReader`) using  `SAXTransformerFactory.newInstance()`. Then set the `CatalogResolver` on the parser using `XMLReader.setEntityResolver()`. Then wrap the `XMLReader` in a `SAXSource`, and supply this as the `Source` object to `Transformer.transform()`.

With Saxon it's also possible to supply the entity resolver indirectly via a configuration property, but this is much more convoluted and is only needed if you aren't able to control the creation and configuration of the `XMLReader` yourself.